# Vagrant ping or curl from guest to host machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, vagrant, ping

I wonder how I can run the command, using the terminal, from my vagrant machine:

`$ ping localhost:3000`

or

`$ curl http://localhost:3000`

In host machine (OSX) I have a rails server running in localhost:3000, so I expect something to show in the rails log.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When I run in the VM:

`$ ip route show`

In the output there is a line like:

`default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 1024`

That is the IP to ping from the guest:

`curl http://10.0.2.2:3000`

Answer (score 10):

Inside the vagrant machine `localhost` refers to the guest vagrant machine, i.e. `localhost` doesn't refer to host machine. One way to access host machine from guest is to configure a [private network](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html). You can specify a static private IP for vagrant, like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end
```

After this guest is accessible from host via `192.168.50.4` and host is accessible from guest via `192.168.50.1`, i.e. the end octate for host's IP will be `1` inside guest machine.

After `vagrant up`, you can do this from inside guest machine:

```
$ ping 192.168.50.1
$ curl http://192.168.50.1:3000
```

Note that, if you have some strict firewall setup then you have to allow connection from `192.168.50.4`.

Comment: That's interesting about the host's ip from the guest ending with 1. Is it documented anywhere? And what happens if you set the guest ip to something ending with a 1? Would the following just not work? `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.1"`

Comment: I tries the first ten and neither of them worked: `curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.33.1:3000; No route to host`

Comment: @tobuslieven this is described in the book Vagrant: Up and Running written the by original creator of Vagrant. If I remember correctly, it was present in the documentation too. However, I could not find it now on the current version of the documentation.

Comment: @embasbm what is the IP that you placed in Vagrantfile. Is this `192.168.50.4` or `192.168.33.4`? Please provide the exact line of the Vagrantfile that you are using. Also you should check your firewall settings.

Comment: @taskinoor This is what I got in my Vagrantfile: `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.64"` Must be something with firewall settings

Comment: Can you ping guest from host `$ ping 192.168.33.64`? If you can ping guest from host but not the opposite then this is probably due to firewall settings. You can disable the firewall temporarily and then check whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set network to "public_network" in the guest machine's config file.

In the `Vageantfile` just uncomment the line:

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

Restart the machine:

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

Do the `ip addr show` and your ip on the public network is the one listed under `eth1` (instead of the usual `eth0`)